# How to uninstall Samsung SmartStation display driver from Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

How to uninstall this Samsung DisplayLink USB display driver for Mac OS X?

*I had some trouble doing this, so I figured I could share it, it might be useful to someone.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get the DMG file you used to install

I personally used this one:
http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201206/20120626165207619/Samsung_Smart_Station_CA650_x.dmg

### Mount it

A double click in the finder should do it

### Extract the setup package

This will create a temp folder on your desktop that you may remove at the end of the procedure.

```
cd ~/Desktop/
mkdir tmp
cd tmp/
tar xf /Volumes/Samsung_Smart_Station_CA750/Setup.app/Contents/Resources/Installers/Samsung_Smart_Station_Lion_10_7.pkg
```

You can/should replace the `pkg` file with the latest that matches your OS (tested here with the "Lion 10.7" package on Yosemite 10.10, it worked).

### Unpack the display driver setup package

```
cd sgfx1072.pkg
cat Payload | gunzip -dc |cpio -i
```

It replied `20340 blocks` on my setup.

### Uninstall the Display Driver

Now we're done, you can either browse with the finder or run this:

```
open Applications/SMSC/SGFX\ Uninstaller.app
```

Your machine will reboot free of this driver.
You may now remove the `tmp` folder that lays on your desktop.

Special thanks to this answer that helped me unpack the `pkg` files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298855/how-unpack-and-pack-pkg-file